# Deleting a Named SharedPreferences File

Tags: android

I'm creating a widget where each widget instance will have its own named SharedPreferences file.  I want to delete that file when the user removes the widget (not just clear the preferences) so over time there isn't a pile of old, empty, useless, files laying around.

The code I'm using clears the file just fine when the widget is removed, however it doesn't actually delete it.  Can anybody see why?

```
@Override
public void onDeleted( Context context, int[] appWidgetIds )
{
    super.onDeleted( context, appWidgetIds );

    /* Delete the SharedPreferences associated with the deleted widget */
    for( int id : appWidgetIds )
    {
        File dir = new File( context.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/shared_prefs" );
        String filename = ConfigurationActivity.getSharedPreferencesFileName( id );
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences( filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        prefs.edit().clear().commit();
        new File( dir, filename ).delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're deleting then calling the preference file? That's going to recreate it.

Comment: `delete` is the last line, or am I missing something?

Comment: Aha. You should be using `context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`. `getFilesDir()` returns a File Object, not a String. Also, remove the SharedPreferences call. That shouldn't be needed if you're just deleting the whole file.

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to add ".xml" to the end of the filename.  I'll remove the SharedPreferences call too, good point, thanks.

Comment: Actually on investigation, SharedPreferences holds data in memory, so the call to it ensures that it's cleared out.